# PLink - Running a Script with output

Tags: shell, batch-file, ssh, plink

Working on automating several scripts that I run regularly. I've got what seemed like it should be an easy one, but I'm having difficulty with it. I'm using VBA to create two files and run this. One text file contains the list of commands and one BAT file containing the plink command initiating it all. Both files are below. The plink.exe and both these files are on the desktop after creation.

The problem is that the script I'm running has output, even when I use the '&' modifier at the end of the command. I'm not allowed to modify the script in any way. When the command file is run, the script runs just fine, but because of the output, the exit command is ignored. I've tried tacking on a sleep command to the end of the script line before the exit and tacking the exit on directly after the script line.

BAT File - Chg.bat

```
plink [user]@[ip] -pw [password] < C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\pcmd.txt
```

Command file - pcmd.txt

```
cd /opt/test/srt
./srt.tool 20150506 20150506 &
exit
```

Comment: Are you interested in the output or not?

Comment: Nope, couldn't care less. Though if we can't completely ignore it, I'm not opposed to it waiting until the output is done before doing the exit command. I've just been unable to do that

Comment: Did you try to redirect it like `./srt.tool 20150506 20150506 > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Alright, so redirecting it works to get it hidden, but now the exit command gets hung up. I get a "You have running jobs" when the exit happens. I've run a ps-ef |grep srt.tool on the server and threw a sleep at the end of the script. By the time the exit command is run after the sleep, srt.tool is done.

Comment: The `srt.tool` runs itself some processes on the background (e.g. using `&`).

Comment: Yep, I just got it to work now. I just moved the sleep from the end of the script line to the beginning of the exit line and now it works. Completely unsure why that works, but I'll take it.

Comment: Please post your solution as as answer.

Comment: Why does this happen? I was having a similar issue. I had `plink user@ip -pw pass "sh run.sh"`. The run.sh had a lot of code that ran fine, but at the end, there was another invocation as `sh another_script.sh;`. This 2nd script did not run correctly. But when I changed it to `sh another_script.sh &; sleep 60; `, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what is now working for me for the script file:

```
cd /test/srt
./srt.tool 20150506 20150506 > /opt/test/srt/test.txt &
rm test.txt
sleep 60; exit
```

Nothing has changed in the Chg.bat file. Apparently directing it, then sleeping before the exit was all that was needed. Not quite as slick as I'd like it, but I'll take working over not working any day